# How to make a directory public and private in a single bucket

Tags: permissions, amazon-s3

I am using amazon S3 bucket to store my data in two different directories in single bucket, I want that my one directory should be globally accessible and another directory should be private. Is there any policy which I can use ?

Comment: There is a detailed answer in [How to set S3 bucket policy to (mostly) private when object acl is public?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106295/how-to-set-s3-bucket-policy-to-mostly-private-when-object-acl-is-public)